# How to properly annotate a cached mixin

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, mixins, jsdoc

```
export function Mixin(base) {
  return class extends base {
    foo = "bar";
  }
}

class A extends Mixin(SuperClass) {

}

let a = new A;
a. // suggests foo
```

This works beautifully, but in my case more often than not `SuperClass` is the same constructor, so I figured it's a good idea to implement caching.

```
let cache = new Map();
export function Mixin(base) {
  if (!cache.has(base)) {
    cache.set(base, class extends base {
      foo = "bar";
    })
  }
  return cache.get(base);
}

class A extends Mixin(SuperClass) {

}

let a = new A;
a. // no longer suggests foo
```

So in order to revive autocomplete I split the action in two functions.

```
let cache = new Map();

function Mixin(base) {
  return class extends base {
    foo = "bar";
  }
}

/** 
 * @returns {ReturnType<Mixin>} 
 */
export function Cached(base) {
  if (!cache.has(base)) {
    cache.set(base, Mixin(base));
  }

  return cache.get(base);
}

class A extends Cached(HTMLElement) {}

let a = new A();

a. // suggests foo
a.inn // does not suggest innerHTML
```

How can I annotate `Cached`'s return value such that it knows it will extend `base`?

I'm thinking something along the lines of the following, just can't figure out what would be the proper syntax:

```
/** 
 * @param {T} base
 * @returns {ReturnType<Mixin> extends T} 
 */
export function Cached(base) {
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, not coming too much from JS, but its likely because `cache` is not typed anyhow, so `return cache.~~` is not known, hence no suggestion.

Comment: @RicHard yes indeed, it could be either `cache` or the return value of `Mixin` it doesn't really matter, the question is how to give it the right type.

Comment: I think the closest you can get is sth like:

/*** @type {{foo, whatever}} */
let a = new A;

a.whatever // will complete.

Comment: @RicHard there must be a proper syntax that will pick up the anonymous class without having to duplicate the information, even if the class has to be named that would still be a valid solution however even then I failed to solve the problem.

Comment: Hey did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: @GuerricP not really, but I opened [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41256) about it, you can go give it some love to get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

The `cache` has the implicit type `Map<any, any>`, it won't infer any other types, because JavaScript is way too permissive for the IDE to detect the exhaustive list of what types go inside the `Map` by parsing the rest of the code (even if you're using an ES6 module and the `cache` is not exported).

If you don't want to change your implementation just for a typing purpose, your best options are to use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [JSDoc type assertions](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html)

Here is a minimal example:

```
let cache = new Map();

/**
 * 
 * @param {*} base 
 * @return {typeof mixin}
 */
export function Mixin(base) {
    /**
    * @alias mixin
    */
    const mixin = class extends base {
        foo = "bar";
    }

    if (!cache.has(base)) {
        cache.set(base, mixin);
    }

    return cache.get(base);
}

class A extends Mixin(SuperClass) {

}

let a = new A;

a. // suggests foo
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example using JSDoc, how do I associate the custom type with the mixin class?

Comment: Don't think this would work. You see, that's the tricky part..

Comment: Yup, looking for references syntax for inner members

Comment: What's grinding my gears is that if the first example works, then this should definitely be possible.

Comment: Yes but the `Map` ruins everything. I've found this solution but it's still not perfect as it makes instantiate a class even if there's a cache hit (the `@alias` doesn't work when in the if block)

Comment: Yep but this defeats the purpose of the cache.. :(

Comment: Indeed. No more time to spend on it atm, will come back later with a real solution

Comment: I made some further findings, if you have a sec maybe a light bulb can light up.

Comment: I'm away from my PC for a while, I'd be glad to know what you found though

Comment: I got it, had to use `ReturnType<>`. Will add to the question. This works for now and gives me all members of my anonymous class, but members of the base class are lost. If you are still interested in this problem I could really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

So this made me have another try which successfully auto-completed at my side.
Hoewever, I had to wrap the `cache` into a scope as follows:

```js
class Foo {
    foo = 'bar';
    fooooooo = 'baaaaaaar';
}

class ClassMaker {
    static _cache = new Map();

    /**
     *
     * @param base
     * @return {Foo}
     */
    static getFromBase(base) {
        if (!ClassMaker._cache.has(base)) {
            ClassMaker._cache[base] = class extends base {
            };
            ClassMaker._cache[base].__proto__ = Foo.__proto__;
        }

        return ClassMaker._cache[base];
    }
}

class Baz {
    baz = 'bar';
}

class Unrelated {
    foooooNotCompletedForReference = 'asd';
}

let a = ClassMaker.getFromBase(Baz);
```

Things thing does auto complete. Also note, it doesn't just show every symbol flying around, i.e., the `Unrelated` class does not get populated into the auto complete helper.

[image: Screenshot Autocomplete]

Note, however, JavaScript is not typed and if you feel like craving for such features you would be better of using TypeScript or Dart for that matter. All those auto suggestions in JavaScript can only be a best effort by analyzing the written code using additional tools. They will be flawed and there is no guarantees anyways.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, after fixing a couple syntax errors I notice that your example also suffers from my additional findings in the accidental solution that I came up with which I posted as an edit to the question.

Comment: You were propably faster fixing the errors. I am not using JS now, still I tried to make it at least compile in my Opera now ;)